# What is an easy recipe for homemade soy sauce?

Tags: recipe-request, soy

I am looking for a recipe which produces soy sauce with a flavor equal to or greater than that found in store bought kikomann brand soy sauce

It is okay if the soy sauce recipe requires many months of fermentation so long as the hands-on working time is less than an hour after we get all of the ingredients.

I found a recipe for soy sauce on the internet, but that recipe requires boiling the beans and gently shaping the boiled beans into something which looks like ocean waves or furrows in a corn field. Only after the beans are sculpted into waves do we allow white fuzzy aspergillus tamarii spores to grow for a few days.

I want to reduce how much time it takes to make the soy sauce subject to a constraint that the soy sauce taste similar to the cheapest brand of factory made soy sauce a person can find.

Sculpting beutiful waves of beans is too much for me to handle.

I know what botulinum is, and I am aware that I might die if I do not kill the bacteria less than 24 hours before using soy sauce on my food. I will boil to death whatever comes out of any recipe you suggest.